# How to get scrollable table in shadcn/ui?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, shadcnui

I m trying to achieve this: A fixed `TableHeader` and a scrollable `TableBody`. From the following code, I can achieve this but the `TableBody` is condensed in the first column. How do I fix this?

```js
export default function TransactionTable() {
  return (
    <Table className="">
      <TableHeader className="">
        <TableRow>
          <TableHead className="w-1/5 px-2 py-1">Date</TableHead>
          <TableHead className="w-2/5 px-2 py-1">Title</TableHead>
          <TableHead className="w-1/5 px-2 py-1">Category</TableHead>
          <TableHead className="w-1/5 px-2 py-1">Amount</TableHead>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHeader>

      <TableBody className="overflow-y-auto  block h-[500px] ">
        {transactions.map((t) => (
          <TableRow key={t.id} className="">
            <TableCell className="px-2 py-1">{t.date}</TableCell>
            <TableCell className="px-2 py-1">{t.title}</TableCell>
            <TableCell className="px-2 py-1">{t.category}</TableCell>
            <TableCell className="px-2 py-1">{t.amount}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Modify you **table.jsx** file (shadcn component)

```js
// other code ...
const Table = React.forwardRef(
  ({ className, containerClassname, ...props }, ref) => (
    <div className={cn("relative w-full", containerClassname)}>
      <table
        ref={ref}
        className={cn("w-full caption-bottom text-sm", className)}
        {...props}
      />
    </div>
  )
);
//other code
```

Step 2: Modify code that you have provided here

```js
export default function TransactionTable() {
  return (
    <Table 
      className=""
      containerClassname="h-fit max-h-80 overflow-y-auto relative"
    >
      <TableHeader className="">
        <TableRow>
          <TableHead className="w-1/5 px-2 py-1">Date</TableHead>
          <TableHead className="w-2/5 px-2 py-1">Title</TableHead>
          <TableHead className="w-1/5 px-2 py-1">Category</TableHead>
          <TableHead className="w-1/5 px-2 py-1">Amount</TableHead>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHeader>

      <TableBody className="overflow-y-auto  block h-[500px] ">
        {transactions.map((t) => (
          <TableRow key={t.id} className="">
            <TableCell className="px-2 py-1">{t.date}</TableCell>
            <TableCell className="px-2 py-1">{t.title}</TableCell>
            <TableCell className="px-2 py-1">{t.category}</TableCell>
            <TableCell className="px-2 py-1">{t.amount}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  );
```